# open /dev/fb0: No such device

Tags: linux, console, framebuffer

I installed fbi framebuffer to view images on TTY terminals (outside X).

When I do:

```
fbi image.jpg
```

it outputs the following error:

> open /dev/fb0 no such device

Yet when I run `ls /dev/fb*`, I can see that I have a directory `/dev/fb` and a character device `/dev/fb0`.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution in [Ubuntu's FrameBuffer wiki entry](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer#Setting%20different%20framebuffer%20resolutions%20in%20GRUB). I had to edit `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and add `vga=ask` to choose the right resolution on boot.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I ended getting Puppy Linux (slacko) to use its main terminal (ctrl alt F1 or exit jwm to command line) to have /dev/fb0 work. I am writing an X program that I wanted to also run outside X and was wondering if puppy had everything or was missing libraries, etc (BTW, I did have to install their -dev package to use gcc tools). Thanks again.